# What is the best way to handle events in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

I'm beginning to learn Ember and it's not clear what the best, most acceptable, or even intended method to handle events is. Is it acceptable to check the target in the click functions event argument, should I make a new view for each item that requires an event other than {{action}}, or something totally different?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IMO you should use the [`{{action}}`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_action) helper where possible. If you want to attach events on a tag in the template, use `{{action}}`; no need to make a new View:

```
<a {{action showPosts href=true}}>All Posts</a>

<form {{action validate target="controller"}}>
  // ...
</form>
```

An exception to the above is when you want to handle more than one events on a specific element:

```
// Template
<ul>
  {{#each post in controller}}
    {{#view App.PostView}}
      {{title}}
      {{#if view.showDetails}}
        <span>{{summary}}</span>
      {{/if}}
    {{/view}}
  {{/each}}
</ul>

// View
App.PostView = Ember.View.extend({
   tagName: li,
   classNames: ['post-item'],
   mouseEnter: function(event) {
     this.set('showDetails', true);
   },

   mouseLeave: function(event) {
     this.set('showDetails', false);
   }
});
```

As we need to capture both `mouseEnter` and `mouseLeave` (to show and hide the details of the post respectively), it is better to do it in the View, avoiding too much logic in the templates. The alternative way for the above would be to use as many nested tags as the number of events we want to handle (in our case, 2):

```
// Template
<ul>
  {{#each post in controller}}
    <li class="post-item" {{action showTheDetails post on="mouseEnter" target="controller"}}>
    <span class="dummy" {{action hideTheDetails post on="mouseLeave" target="controller"}}
      {{title}}
      {{#if post.showDetails}}
        <span>{{summary}}</span>
      {{/if}}
    </span<
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

And then in the controller:

```
// Controller
App.PostsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
   showTheDetails: function(event) {
     var post = event.context;
     post.set('showDetails', true);
   },

   hideTheDetails: function(event) {
     var post = event.context;
     post.set('showDetails', false);
   }
});
```

But I think you will agree that this is uglier. See [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/569).

---

In cases where you want to use Ember control views ([Ember.TextField](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.TextField.html), [Ember.TextArea](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.TextArea.html), etc.) you have no choice but to capture events in the View. So you extend the control view and define the event handlers in the View:

```
// Template
<legend>Add a comment</legend>
{{view App.CommentInputField valueBinding="comment"}}

// View
App.CommentInputField = Ember.TextField.extend({ 
  focusOut: function(event) {
    this.get('controller').validateComment();
  },

  keyDown: function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) { // Enter key
      this.get('controller').createComment();
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: FYI: Events such as `mouseEnter` or `mouseLeave` should not be handled by the action helper (see discussion in https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1011 and specific comment https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1011#issuecomment-6367539)

Comment: Okay, so in the end if you have a lot of events that the {{action}} helper method isn't suited for, you'll end up having quite a few views.